# Using s:select element

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I am trying to use a `s:select` element to set the value of an object property on an action. The property is not initialized (null) and has a getter and setter. The property's class also has the appropriate getters and setters:

```
public class MyProperty {
    private String myField;
    public String getMyField() { return myField; }
    public void setMyField(String myField) { this.myField = myField; }
}
```

I have had no difficulty accomplishing this using the `s:textfield` element, the input form both generates and accepts/returns the value: `<s:textfield name="myProperty.myField" />`.

When I attempt to do the same using an s:select element, an error occurs when generating the input form.

The element is: `<s:select name="myProperty.myField" [... list/listKey/listValue...] />`

The error is: `"ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "myField")"`.

I have found that the error can be resolved by initializing the property in the action (`myProperty = new MyProperty();`), but this both seems awkward (having to do something special depending on the interface element that will be used), and will not work in the actual use case. This solution seems odd since my understanding was that OGNL was happy to instantiate objects as they were referenced (such as when I used the `s:textfield`), so long as they did not exist already.

The actual use case is an input form that has a list of pairs of select elements (columns to sort by and sort direction). The intention is that the JSP page be able to allow some arbitrary number of these pairs, and that the action should work with whatever size list it receives. Because the action would not know the size of the list before before the input form JSP was generated, it would not be possible to initialize the correct number of elements beforehand.

**Question:** What is the best way to use an object property with a s:select element, such that the solution can also work with the property being a list of objects where the size of the list is not known beforehand?

My particular version of Struts 2 is 2.3.1.2, if that is relevant.

---

In case it impacts the answer to the question, or my question was unclear, what I am trying to end up with is effectively:

```
<s:select name="sort[0].criterion" [...] />
<s:select name="sort[0].order" [...] />
<s:select name="sort[1].criterion" [...] />
<s:select name="sort[1].order" [...] />
[maybe some more pairs...]
```

...

```
private List<SortOrderPair> sort = new ArrayList<SortOrderPair>();
public SortOrderPair getSort() { return sort; }
public void setSort(SortOrderPair sort) { this.sort = sort; }
```

Comment: I've the feeling that some crucial info is missing here. Is `list` attribute pointing to the right collection ? Does `MyProperty` has a default constructor (or no constructor) ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yes, all of the attributes of the `s:select` element are presumably correct, because I can change myProperty to be a String instead of an object (and drop `.myField` from the name attribute) and then it functions as expected. Yes, MyProperty has a default constructor, as mentioned if I use that default constructor in the action it also functions (though this is not as expected).

Comment: Please, try changing `sort` to `foobar`, just to be sure that word isn't filtered somewhere. If it doesn't work, I'm afraid you will have to post `SortOrderPair` code, your full `<s:select/>` tags, and struts configuration, because I ran out of ideas...

Comment: Also check in the whole page if you have something ELSE named `sort`, and try printing the content of ValueStack with  <s:debug/> (in devMode) and CTRL+F for `sort` there...

Comment: @AndreaLigios It may have been unclear from my question, but the MyProperty code is actually implemented/failing, since I wanted to eliminate the possibility that "sort" was a keyword for something.

Comment: Aah, yes, it was unclear to me, my fault probably. I don't know why it doesn't work, but I don't get why you need to do that, the framework has specific OGNL layers handling this stuff, for which reason are you adding your own ? `can also work with the property being a list of objects where the size of the list is not known beforehand?` : isn't enough to use an iterator ?

Comment: Well, my expectation was that the OGNL layer would handle it (action has a property that is a list, JSP references members of that list that don't exist, OGNL regognises this and instantiates using default constructor), it just... isn't handling it. I'm more than happy to accept a solution that uses an iterator, though note that the list is either empty or null when the input form is generated (form decides how many `s:select` elements to present, action has only an empty or null list until input form is submitted).